# Testing software on lots of PCI cards

Tags: windows, hardware, testing, pci

I am developing software that needs to work across the largest possible array of PCI adapter cards.  Consider PCI ethernet cards.  I can collect dozens of different cards, and I have a Windows XP machine dedicated to testing.  My first guess is to have a partition snapshot and keep overlaying the system partition to return to known state before each adapter install and test.  Are there any other tools or tips for such a hardware testing and qualification process?  For example, are there products for organizing hardware data, such as to automatically record all the PCI IDs, etc., of a new adapter into a database, sniff out exactly what set of driver files were added to Windows to support this adapter, etc., etc.?

Comment: This *might* be better suited to stackoverflow.com

Comment: Something puzzles me here. If your software runs on Windows XP, then why do you care about hardware *at all*? That's what the O.S. and its drivers are for...

Answer (score 3):

Consider approaching a WHQL certification lab.  I picked one at random off of Google: http://www.jungo.com/st/whql_certification.html

Their primary focus is on certifying a specific device, but their sales people may be able to point you towards labs that do specifically what you want.  It's probably easier to outsource the work if your lawyers will let it be so.